# MKMapView Content Insets with Navigation Bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mapkit

I'm experiencing a strange issue with MKMapView placed in a view with a navigation bar. Given a UIScrollView in the same situation, whose width, height, and center are constrained to it's superview (the view controller's `view` object) the insets will be adjusted if the controller's `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` property is set to `YES`, and not if set to `NO`. That's great. I can not find this documented anywhere, but the map view seems to do the same thing, but it's not possible to disable it. Setting `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` has no effect.

In brief(ish):

**In  the image below, the small back square is centered within the view, regardless of navigation bar. The map view is also constrained to be exactly the size of the view (it extends behind the nav bar). The location of the map view was set to be the current location (also indicated by the blue circle) so I would expect them to match, but they are off by half the combined height of status and navigation bars.**

**Is there an explanation for this behavior, and a way to get it to work as expected?**

[image: Screenshot of MKMapView acting a fool]

This is very strange because an MKMapView is not a subclass of a UIScrollView but it is behaving like one in this case. That's not completely unreasonable, but I would expect the auto adjusting insets to work consistently on a map view and a scroll view.

### Workaround

Something awful like this would 'solve the problem':

```
MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(self.coordinate, MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.008, 0.008));
MKMapRect mapRect = MKMapRectForCoordinateRegion(region);
[self.mapView setVisibleMapRect:mapRect edgePadding:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 64, 0) animated:YES];
```

Either adjusting the bottom inset as well, or adding a negative inset on the top gets things lined up, but it would break if this behavior of the map view changes, or if the view controller is presented without a navigation bar, or if there is a stiff breeze. It also erodes my confidence in pulling correct coordinates back out of the map view.

Comment: How are you adding the mapview to the view controller, programmatically or using IB? Also, what are you doing to add that dot to the view?

Comment: @Mike The view controller is set up in a storyboard file, including the map view and the dot. The dot is just a view which is centered in the view controller's root view and has a fixed size.

Comment: Anthony, did you find a good solution for this? I have the same situation and I am hesitant to employ your workaround as I would be concerned about confidence in correct coordinates with this solution and any future changes made to MKMapView behavior.

Comment: @heading_to_tahiti No, I never found a solution that I was confident in. I think in the end we switched to an opaque status bar to avoid the problem.

Answer (score 6):

`MKMapView` does indeed sit under the navigation bar, but automatically uses a housing view controller's `topLayoutGuide` to shift annotations and the compass view, etc. down from under it.

You should make sure that your own views take this into account in their autolayout code.

Comment: That sounds consistent with my experience. Is this behavior documented anywhere? Do you know if there is a way to change this behavior and disregard the `topLayoutGuide`?

Answer (score -1):

If you take a look at this, you can see that the mapview is very likely not sitting under the navigation bar, as you think. It is sitting between the bottom of the nav bar and the bottom of the superview.

On another note, the navigation bar is translucent by default, so if the mapview was really sitting under the nav bar you would be able to see through it, assuming you didn't disable the default nav bar behavior.

[image]

Comment: Sorry it's not very clear in the screenshot, but the map view does extend beneath the navigation bar. It's more obvious when you pan a bit of highway behind it. You're illustration does a great job of showing where the 'half of the status bar and nav bar height' comes from, but does not solve the problem. Depending on how you set up the constraints you can get the two different behaviors. Aligning the top of the map view to the top layout guide will behave as you say, but setting the height and centerY equal to the super view will extend it under the nav bar.

Comment: It's also worth noting, extending beneath the nav bar is the standard behavior and the goal in this case. But, using an opaque bar and aligning the map and other views to the top layout guide would be a much safer workaround than what I suggest in the question.

Comment: Here's a simple project to illustrate: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1881314/MapTest.zip

Comment: Yeah, even if you put the dot's center in the mapview's center, is it still above the dot. It appears they must handle it funky under the covers and put the user location dot centered under the nav bar.. I tried a few things but to no avail. Sorry :/